# Making list items style independantly of each other

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a ul with several list items inside made up of h3s and lis with the class id of "close".

I have a hover style that expands the letter spacing on the h3s, the problem is, the items with the close class expand as well. I've tried a few different things before adding the class, like nth child etc (all which are visible in the code). I would like the close classed lis to remain the same size when the h3s are expanded.

Any help is appreciated.

jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/snowwhyte/7eLmarnp/7/#&togetherjs=Uq5j49dUG0

CSS:

```
a {text-decoration:none;
}
li {list-style:none;
}
}
#openClose {
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    margin-top:55px;
}

#openClose li{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:block;
    padding-right:-50px;
}

#openClose li:nth-child(2n+2){
    margin:30px 0 100px 0;
    background-color:#000;
    border:2px #fff solid;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:1rem;
    padding:10px 0 10px 0;
}
#openClose li:nth-child(2n+2):hover{
letter-spacing:-0.1rem; 
transition:.3s;
}

#openClose li a h3{
font-family:Helvetica, Gotham, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color:#73a6c2;
}

.close{
}

#openClose li a h3:hover{color:#fff;
text-shadow:2px 1px 2px #000;
transition:.2s;
letter-spacing:1rem;
}

a:visited { text-decoration: none; color:#B8CEDB; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; color:#D7D8D8; }
a:focus { text-decoration: none; color:#fff;
```

}

HTML:

```
<section id="openClose">
<ul>
<li><a href="#wrapper"><h3>Tool Descriptions</h3></a></li>
<li class="close"><a href="#">Close</a></li>
<li><a href="#wrapper2"><h3>Key tools</h3></a></li>
<li class="close"><a href="#">Close</a></li>
<li><a href="#wrapper3"><h3>Adjustment Layers & <br>
Blending modes</h3></a></li>
<li class="close"><a href="#">Close</a></li>
</ul></section>
```

Comment: You could just add a different class or id to each list item and style each accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that the size of the li containing the `h3` tag is expanding with the `h3`, which then expands the `ul` to fit it,and in turn, all of the block level children of the `ul`. Can we have some context regarding what the purpose of the effect you're trying to achieve will be? There may be a much better way of going about it.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you don't have any element with a defined width, so every elements have the width of the largest element.

To do what you're trying to achive, you have plenty of solutions depending on your needs.

You could define a fix width on one of the parents, like the ul for example and add the `white-space: nowrap` property to the h3 (see [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7eLmarnp/10/)) :

```
ul {
    width: 200px;
}
#openClose li a h3{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You could also set a fix width on your li with the close button (see [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7eLmarnp/11/)) :

```
#openClose li:nth-child(2n+2){
   width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try. Like you see i changed a little your code joining some things and clean a little, but the point is in the `width` property of `.close`

https://jsfiddle.net/7eLmarnp/12/